# How to get access to generated text box inside Silverlight DataForm?

Tags: silverlight, dataform

I have a DataForm bound to a simple object that has some text fields. The DataForm correctly auto generates a TextBox for each of the string fields. From code I now need to set the focus to one of those generated TextBox elemetns. How do you get the generated element from the DataForm so I can set focus to it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `AutoGeneratingField` event of `DataForm`.
Here is example how to get property with name **ID**

```
   
void dataForm1_AutoGeneratingField(object sender, DataFormAutoGeneratingFieldEventArgs e)
{
   if (e.PropertyName == "ID")
   {
       // set focus
   }
}
```